QtWebEngineView not working after compiling with nuitka in Python
Took some of the code from my launcher. I display the window with the site through PySide2 and QWebEngineView. Everything works fine with Python IDLE. When I compile with nuitka, the code crashes. If I output a normal window without the web module, everything works fine. Here is the code itself:
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import logging

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 700)
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))

        # window

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Semibold")

        self.main_window_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_window_frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 10, 1000, 700))
        self.main_window_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54,57,62)")
        self.main_window_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.main_window_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.main_window_frame.setObjectName("main_window_frame")

        # (dont ask me what is it)

        self.tab_menu_frame3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.main_window_frame)
        self.tab_menu_frame3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 1000, 650))
        self.tab_menu_frame3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(54,57,62)")
        self.tab_menu_frame3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.tab_menu_frame3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.tab_menu_frame3.setObjectName("tab_menu_frame3")

        # web engine
        self.web_view = QWebEngineView(self.main_window_frame)
        self.web_view.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 50, 1000, 650))
        self.web_view.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl('https://example.com'))
        try:
            self.web_view.show()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error: {e}")

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    try:
        w = MainWindow()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {e}")

nuitka options:
python -m nuitka --onefile --windows-console-mode=force --enable-plugin=pyside2 --standalone  test.pyw

The console (cmd C:\test.exe) displays this:
QtWebEngine resources not found at C:/Temp/ONEFIL~1/PySide2/resources... Trying parent directory…

Qt WebEngine resources not found at C:/Temp/ONEFIL~1/PySide2... Trying application directory…

Qt WebEngine resources not found at C:/Temp/onefile_9968_133754483410059208. Trying fallback directory… The applicatio

n MAY NOT work.

Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location C:/Temp/ONEFIL~1/PySide2/translations\qtwebengine_locales

Trying application directory…

Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location C:/Temp/onefile_9968_133754483410059208\qtwebengine_locales. Trying

fallback directory… Translations MAY NOT not be correct.

[1107/151902.529:ERROR: icu_util.cc (251)] Couldn't mmap icu data file


I tried changing the code from PyQt5 to PySide2 because I thought nuitka with PyQt5 was compiling qtwebengineview with errors, but nothing changed. Tried changing nuitka parameters, nothing changed. I expected it to be easier

Programs like nuitka can only make guesses about what they should include in the package, and complex modules like QtWebEngine also require binary resources that those programs are not able to know about. Check this issue and do some research on the repository issues. Also see this possibly related post.

I removed the --onefile from nuitka options and everything worked. thanks
